# Is changing an element's ID universally supported?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I will have to toggle an ID on a `<div>` and was wondering if toggling element IDs will cause any errors.

Some people do not like this for stylistic reasons, but this question is **not** about that. I am asking whether it will cause any errors and whether it causes bad effects to do so.

Comment: Why dont you test it? I think it will work but bad practice

Comment: What do you have against toggling class instead? it seem to make more sense. Depending on how you target an element by id I think toggling an id might affect it. Why do you have to toggle by id? perhaps there is another aproach

Comment: Classes are often used to represent some state of the component (e.g. disabled or active). IDs however are more of a means to uniquely identify an element. While it should be perfectly fine to toggle the ID, it feels a bit odd.

Comment: Also you will need to keep track of the current id of the tag. Why add that extra hassle to your code

Comment: Toggling a `data-*` attribute might be as simple and can be targeted with CSS as well.

Comment: Toggling classes would be more practical. Otherwise, you may loose track of that ID. ID's are meant to identify the element uniquely. Classes are *generally* used to apply a "type" or "group" to an element. However, a class would allow you to select multiple elements if necessary. Keep it scalable.

Comment: There are certain UI libraries out there that use an ID to register event handlers on certain UI elements/containers.  I agree it doesn't make a bit of sense for something built purely for use in the UI layer to have an ID, but not anything I can do about it until they change it.  The question is valid and aside from the possibility of running into duplicate ID's on a page, which still actually works by the way - I haven't seen an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Rather than toggling (deleting) an ID I would consider just appending an "X" at the end, and then removing it.

Comment: I don't think there are any browsers that don't support toggling the id and if by "universally supported" you mean all modern browsers they all support the setAttribute() function. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: w3fools guys are coming... 3 2 1

Comment: Everyone commenting should read the whole question. This question is **not** about whether this is good style.

Comment: @HaSuKrOnOs, maybe you haven't heard yet, but [w3fools](https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools/issues/50) is no more.

Comment: @zzzBov not know, but I'm just kidding, whenever you link w3schools a w3fools guy arrives

Comment: @HaSuKrOnOs Sorry to get side tracked, but I would be remiss if I did not comment: Paul Irish should have never made the site to begin with, it was childish & it didn't even work, because the site was crude & inflammatory; not the right way way to go about exciting change.  Negativity like that isn't so different from Trolling, and helps fuel the fire burning down the free internet.  This is the right way to do things: http://openrespect.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling the id should not cause any errors or other side effects as long as the id is not repeated on a page.

You can go ahead and do it.

You can also check out the rules of using the id attribute correctly here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

This article describes the new specifications of the id atribute in HTML5:

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: Those rules for the ID attribute are out of date. They've changed in HTML 5.

Comment: I have tested it several times now on the following browsers so I am now at the stage where I am canvassing the internet asking for input to make doubly sure that this isn't going to cause an outage once I push it out.  This is ridiculous, but I'm being all but forced to commit this change by my Front-End Architect.  Welcome to big money corporate Web Development, right?

IE8 (Win7), 9 (Win7), 10 (Win7, Win8, Win8.1), 11 (Win8, Win8.1), FF (latest), Safari (latest in OSX-latest), Chrome (latest - Win7 & OSX-latest) --> as of this week.